# Failed to import tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, importerror

```
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>            
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
    

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

                        

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                       
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>                            
                                    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>                     
        from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>                
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>                   
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>            
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\deepz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>            
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.



Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.


See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

on `importing TensorFlow as tf`
I am getting this error please can someone help me to solve this problem.
system HP 245 G5 and operating system windows 10 2004 version

Comment: Please use code formater for improving code readibility. 
I would recommend you to set up a new clean environment and reeinstall the desired tensorflow version

Answer (score 3):

If you have Anaconda installed I recommend you use Conda to install tensorflow into a new environment. Reason is Conda installs tensorflow and the required Cuda Toolkit and the proper version of cuDNN. Pip does not install these and you have to download them seperately, unzip and store them in directories. You also have to adjust you environment variable to point to these directories.